# Can I create a pf rule involving MAC address instead of IP?

Tags: firewall, mac-address, openbsd, pf

The title is self explanatory.

I want to create rules in pf running on OpenBSD 4.9 for perticular MAC address, something like

```
pass in on eth0 from mac 00:04:34:5f:34:33 to mac 34:32:34:06:5e:22
```

I have read [this](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/tagging.html), but it doesn't help!!

Answer (score 2):

If i remember well, you can't. You can only filter mac address when you do it on a bridge if

Answer (score 2):

As mandrake pointed out you can't filter by MAC address directly in PF (it's an IP packet filter, it knows not of this "ethernet" thing).

What you CAN do, if your system is acting as a bridge, is *tag* packets based on MAC address, and then filter based on the tag.

From the [pf FAQ](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/tagging.html):

> ### Tagging Ethernet Frames
>
> Tagging can be performed at the Ethernet level if the machine doing
> the tagging/filtering is also acting as a bridge(4). By creating
> bridge(4) filter rules that use the tag keyword, PF can be made to
> filter based on the source or destination MAC address. Bridge(4) rules
> are created using the ifconfig(8) command.
> Example:
>
> `# ifconfig bridge0 rule pass in on fxp0 src 0:de:ad:be:ef:0 tag USER1`
>
> And then in pf.conf:
>
> `pass in on fxp0 tagged USER1`

Comment: as i mentioned in the question, I have read that page...but why should my machine act as bridge?? can't I use ifconfig to tag frames from a perticular machine(MAC) and then use the tagged packet for pf?? Why being a bridge is a such a necessity?

Comment: @VineetMenon "Because that's how it works" -- tagging is a facility provided by [bridge(4)](http://resin.csoft.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=4&topic=bridge) interfaces. As far as I'm aware there's no way to tag (by MAC address) without involving a bridge.  The assumption is that you are building a firewall, which is a fancy packet-filtering bridge between `inside` and `outside` interfaces.

Comment: actually, i am using openbsd as a fw, but haven't created a bridge, rather have set packet forwarding to 1 in `/etc/sysctl`. Does issueing that command produces a bridge internally?? Can you refer me some nice references where i can read about it?

Comment: @VineetMenon http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/ is the canonical reference for ALL things `pf`-related. I didn't write it, but everything I know is in there.